# T4 code generation during build, custom assembly reference

Tags: .net, msbuild, t4

I have a T4 template that processes several .tt files in my project.  I also have some custom classes I've defined to help with the code transformation process.

```
<#@ template language="C#"  hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)\MyDependency.dll" #>
```

This works in Visual Studio, I have a VS Macro which defines $(TargetDir) correctly.

Now, I want to perform the code generation process during my build process.  I added:

```
<TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
<OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
<IncludeDslT4Settings>true</IncludeDslT4Settings> <ItemGroup>
<T4ReferencePath Include="$(OutputPath)" />
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TextTemplating\v10.0\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

My build runs, but I get:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TextTemplating\v10.0\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets
>   (407): The host threw an exception while trying to resolve the
>   assembly reference '$(TargetDir)\MyDependency.dll'. The transformation
>   will not be run. The following Exception was thrown:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: The given assembly name or codebase was
>   invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)    at
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(RuntimeAssembly& assembly,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean raiseResolveEvent)    at
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit()    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.GlobalAssemblyCacheHelper.GetLocation(String
>   strongName)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Sdk.Host.GenericTextTemplatingHost.ResolveAssemblyReference(String
>   assemblyReference)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ResolveAssemblyReferences(ITextTemplatingEngineHost
>   host, TemplateProcessingSession session). Line=-1, Column=-1

Obviously it won't resolve `$(TargetDir)` in Team build context.

I tried adding TargetDir to my build configuration's property group, to no avail.  This value doens't pass through to the context of the T4 Code Generator.

I don't want to use an environment variable.

How can I set `$(TargetDir)` correctly in Team Build context?

Comment: Oleg Sych wrote about msbuild integration:
http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/#IncludeFolders . I can't tell if it resolves your problem but it seems to be a pretty good guide on the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see where $(OutputPath) is defined by visual studio. did you try $(TargetDir) in your  item w/in your project? Then you can remove the $(TargetDir)\ from your Assembly declaration in the T4 file.

I just worked through a slew of possibilities to get something similar to work, will be doing a blog post today or tomorrow.

So:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <T4ReferencePath Include="$(TargetDir)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

in your csproj, and

```
<#@ assembly name="MyDependency.dll" #>
```

in your T4 file

Comment: Here's the promised blog post. Sorry for the lateness!

http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2013/06/15/t4-gotchyas-in-your-environment/