# T4Scaffolding assembly MSBuild variables not resolving

Tags: msbuild, angular-kendo, t4scaffolding

I have an open source project where I am having to instruct users to place a dll in c:\NPEG.dll 
https://github.com/leblancmeneses/AngularKendo.IntegrationTests/blob/master/AngularKendo.IntegrationTests/CodeTemplates/Scaffolders/T4WithNUnitFeature/T4WithNUnitFeatureTemplate.cs.t4

Instead I would like to support: <#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)NPEG.dll" #>
https://github.com/leblancmeneses/RobustHaven.IntegrationTests/blob/master/T4/CodeTemplates/Scaffolders/T4WithNUnitFeature/T4WithNUnitFeatureTemplate.cs.t4

However, this results in references messing, assembly loading error because it cannot be found.

NPEG.dll will be in the bin directory.

**Does anyone know how I can resolve a relative dll with T4Scaffolding?**

## Edit

#### Steps to Reproduce

I've checked in the csproj changes.  Assembly reference should work with both: "NPEG.dll" and "$(myLibFolder)NPEG.dll"  - however, it does not

- Clone the project here:
  https://github.com/leblancmeneses/AngularKendo.IntegrationTests/tree/T4Scaffolding
- Package Manager Console set the default project to: "AngularKendo.IntegrationTests"
- Run the following command in Package Manager Console

.

```
  Scaffold T4WithNUnitFeature "Gherkin\NgModelDotNotationIsInitialized.feature" -Force
```

#### References

- http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2013/06/15/t4-gotchyas-in-your-environment/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/t4/archive/2013/08/29/what-s-new-in-t4-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you seen [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145821/t4-code-generation-during-build-custom-assembly-reference)? It looks like what you need.

Comment: I've tried those links in the past and just created a branch with my changes. (see question edit)  I believe it has to do with T4Scaffolding specific host not passing those variables down to my script. - thanks